# How to access the external SDRAM?

Tags: bare-metal, pi-1

Is it possible to access the external 512 MB SDRAM (on my Pi B+) from a bare-metal program? If yes, how would I do so?

Do I have to configure and use the MMU for it? I don't want to handle virtual addresses if I don't have to.

Comment: Why do you call the memory external?  Of course you can access memory from a bare metal program.  Why not follow a bare metal Pi tutorial?  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=72

Comment: Because it is soldered onto the chip, it's not inside the chip.

Comment: how much ram is "inside the chip"?

Comment: the ram is directly sandwiched to the top of the memory control circuitry in the CPU .... it is no longer a separate entity .... it is "inside the chip" ... it is a multi-layer CPU

Comment: External memory has never been a term used for the working memory used by a computer.  You don't call a PC's RAM chips external just because they are situated elsewhere on the motherboard.  External memory is generally the term used for persistent storage when the PC is switched off.